# Android - Polyline encoding algorithm?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my android project I have List of GeoPoints. I have a [algorithm to decode](http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java/) the encoded polyline string. Can anyone help me for encoding the List of GeoPoints to polyline string in-order to save this in Shared Preferences.

Comment: on the link you posted you can find an implementation in Javascript. Simply port that to java.http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/googlemaps/encodepolyline/PolylineEncoder.js

Answer (score 15):

you should include the new [googlemaps utils library for Android](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/) and then use [PolyUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html):

```
PolyUtil.encode(latLngPath)
PolyUtil.decode(encodedPath)
```

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils for the latest version of the library.

Answer (score 5):

For Java generally, the official [Google Maps Services for Java](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) library has a utility, too.

```
PolylineEncoding.decode(String);
PolylineEncoding.encode(List<LatLng>); // Note that this is not the Android LatLng
```

Code is [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/maps/internal/PolylineEncoding.java).

Answer (score 4):

From Google:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/c85319eb7fd930dc

Seems like an Java Polyline impl. in progress.

From Github:

https://github.com/markrambow/JavaPolylineEncoder

https://github.com/petpen/JavaPolylineEncoder2

And the spec is here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm

Answer (score 0):

Added this library work for me :

```
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:2.2.0'

PolylineEncoding.decode(String);
PolylineEncoding.encode(List<LatLng>);
```